# Cannot pass getElementByID object to external JS file on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, external

I've created a simple JS file, called *formValueOperator.js*, containing this function:

```
function setValue(type, obj, value){
if(type == 'text')
{
    obj.value = value;
}
```

and another HTML page calling this function:

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <title>Simple Test</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="formValueOperator.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function setInitValue(){
              var element_order_id = document.getElementById("order_id");
              setValue('text', element_order_id, 'aaa');
         }
      </script>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
         <FORM name="myform" method="post">
              <input type="text" size=20 id="order_id" name="order_id">
         </FORM>
         <script type="text/javascript">
              setInitValue();
         </script>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

It's quite a simple operation:

Run HTML --> call function setInitValue() --> put 'aaa' in text box.

Everything work perfectly on FireFox (7.0.1). However, when I tried to run this on Chrome (14.0.835.202), it didn't work at all.

Then, I tested the code by moving entire ***setValue*** function from ***formValueOperator.js*** and pasted it in HTML page. Surprisingly, it worked.

There must be something fishy about how Chrome pass getElementByID object to external JS file.

Could anyone please help me on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way, delaying the method execution until the web-pages has been loaded:

```
<FORM name="myform" method="post">
   <input type="text" size=20 id="order_id" name="order_id" />
</FORM>

<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
      setInitValue();
  };
</script>
```

Comment: There is no closing tag for input in HTML and self closing tags don't exist in HTML either.

Comment: @Jamie Dixon: Really? But what about this? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: The page you show says: "In HTML, the <input> tag has no end tag.

In XHTML, the <input> tag must be properly closed, like this <input />."

Comment: @Jamie Dixon: That's Right. Thanks for the warning :) I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with when the `setInitValue()` method is fired.

When you move your method outside of the JS file and into the body of the document you're probably delaying the executing of the method a few milliseconds giving the element you're selecting time to load.

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event to execute your code when everything has finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInitValue();
 }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for a fast response. 

However, After testing, it still didn't work on Chrome (but work on FireFox).

Comment: In your origional question, when you says "it didn't work atal", what exactly do you mean? what error do you get?

Comment: No error shown, just a blank text box.

But when I run this page on FireFox, it showed 'aaa' within text box.

Comment: Is it finding the element you're trying to select? Throw out an alert or console.log with element_order_id to see if it's undefined.

Comment: Ok, I put an alert(obj.value) in the JS file. FireFox seems to answer with 'aaa' value, while Chrome did't response at all.

Comment: alert out the element_order_id variable. We need to know if it contains anything.

Comment: Both FF and Chrome returned 'object HTMLInputElement'.

Comment: And when I tried *element_order_id.value*, FF returned an alert windows with 'aaa' while Chrome alerted with a blank alert window.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you running? Does this sample work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/m6aua/1/

Comment: My Chrome version is 14.0.835.202. And the sample was running fine. (which make me wonder why?)

Comment: Oops! Please ignore my last post on Chrome alerted with a blank alert window. I misplaced some code there.

Comment: So, my point is that, on Chrome, if both HTML and JS code were in the same file, it work. But whenever you separated them, it won't.

Comment: Personally I'd use jQuery and avoid using obj.value. Using jQuery you can do $("#order_id").val(); This is more likely to work than doing it the other way.